# Approved behaviour of disconnected router receiving DHCP discover packet

Tags: dhcp

What is the normal/approved behaviour of a router if it receives a DHCP discover packet when it has no connection to the Internet?

Background: I have lost my home broadband connection. The ISP (Virgin Media) want to send an engineer, who cannot come for a week.  However, various evidence suggests to me that it is just the router that is broken, and if I could convince the ISP of that, I could perhaps get a new router more quickly.  Anyway, I would like to understand the situation.

Two different PCs fail to connect through the router via cables, and a phone fails to connect wirelessly, so it cannot be a problem with the network card in the PC.

Wireshark shows my PC sending out DHCP discover packets.  I think that if the router received these packets and it was working correctly, then it should reply even if there was no connection from the router to the external Internet.   Is my understanding correct here?

In fact, I see no packets of any kind coming back from the router.

Comment: You have done a reset on the router? That should restore the default behaviour of DHCP enabled (just in case you accidentally disabled it).

Comment: Yes, I have reset the router and performed many other checks before resorting to Wireshark.